# Sending a post message via retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is my first go with retrofit but I am trying to send an array of Gps data points to my server

from my device

this is my POJO class

```
public class GpsData {

    private long mId;
    @SerializedName("mduid")
    @Expose
    private String mMduid;
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private double mLat;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private double mLng;
    @SerializedName("speed")
    @Expose
    private float mSpeed;
    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    private long mTime;
    private boolean mSent;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String mStatus;
```

and this is my Request class that holds the list

```
public class GpsRequest {
    @SerializedName("gpsData")
    @Expose
    public List<GpsData> data;
}
```

this is my interface

```
public interface GpsApiInterface {

    @Headers( "Content-Type: application/json" )
    @POST("/api/v2/GPS")
    Call<ResponseBody> sendGpsData(@Body GpsRequest gpsData);
}
```

This is how I make the request

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://"+ DEBUG_API)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        GpsApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(GpsApiInterface.class);

        ArrayList<GpsData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(data);
        list.add(data);
        GpsRequest request = new GpsRequest();
        request.data = list;

            Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.sendGpsData(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if(response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                        GpsDB db = new GpsDB(LocationService.this);
                        db.delete(GpsDB.ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
                        db.close();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

This is the server code I am using to test

```
public class GPSController : ApiController
    {
        public GPSController() { }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]GPSData[] gpsData)
        {
            if (gpsData != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gpsData.Length; i++)
                {

                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }


        }
    }
```

This is the GPS data class on the server

```
public class GPSData
    {
        public string mduid;
        public double latitude;
        public double longitude;
        public int speed;
        public string time;
        public string status;
    }
```

when I make the request the server gets hit but there is no data (gpsData is null). if I make the same call from `postman` it gets called and the data is there so what am I missing?

**Update**

Added logging to okhttp and this is the log

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.202.170:9001/api/v2/GPS http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 247
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
D/OkHttp: Host: 192.168.202.170:9001
D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Accept-Encoding: gzip
D/OkHttp: User-Agent: okhttp/3.6.0
D/OkHttp: {"gpsData":[{"mId":0,"latitude":43.0360532,"longitude":-78.8010079,"mSent":false,"speed":0.0,"status":"OK","time":1492088158526},{"mId":0,"latitude":43.0360532,"longitude":-78.8010079,"mSent":false,"speed":0.0,"status":"OK","time":1492088158526}]}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (247-byte body)
```

Comparing the Json that works from `Postman`

```
[
    {
        "latitude": 43.0360532,
        "longitude": -78.8010079,
        "speed": 0,
        "time": 1492027407344
    },
    {
        "latitude": 43.0360532,
        "longitude": -78.8010079,
        "speed": 0,
        "time": 1492027407344
    }
]
```

to the data being sent from the app

```
{
    "gpsData": [
        {
            "mId": 0,
            "latitude": 43.0360532,
            "longitude": -78.8010079,
            "mSent": false,
            "speed": 0,
            "status": "OK",
            "time": 1492088158526
        },
        {
            "mId": 0,
            "latitude": 43.0360532,
            "longitude": -78.8010079,
            "mSent": false,
            "speed": 0,
            "status": "OK",
            "time": 1492088158526
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems that since `gpsData` on the server is an array but the app is sending an object with an array may be the problem? if so how do I send an array not in an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was sending an object with an array and the server is only expecting an array so I changed the request to this

```
@POST("/api/v2/GPS")
Call<ResponseBody> sendGpsData(@Body List<GpsData> gpsData);
```

and it is working correctly now

Answer (score 1):

You need a constructor for your GPSRequest class:

```
public class GpsRequest {
    @SerializedName("gpsData")
    @Expose
    public List<GpsData> data;
    public GpsRequest(List<GpsData> data) {
         this.data = data;
    }
```

And then in your request:

```
GpsRequest request = new GpsRequest(list);
```

Comment: Adding a constructor didn't help, still get null on the server

Comment: You sure your list is not empty? Also, you can debug your request by adding loggingInterceptor [Retrofit 2 — Log Requests and Responses](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses)

Comment: I just updated my post with request logging and the differences between a working json and non working

Comment: @tyczj You are sending a list of the data in your Post request, if you want to send exactly what you did in Postman, just modify your request to GpsApiInterface with `Call<ResponseBody> sendGpsData(@Body GpsData gpsData);`

Comment: I don't get it, what change in `GpsRequest` with introducing the constructor. `data` list is public, setting it through the constructor or via object instance have the same effect..

Answer (score 0):

Digression to POJO model. `@Expose` annotation in POJO got no effect if you create Gson instance with `GsonConverterFactory.create()` (since the `Gson` instance in the background is created with `new Gson()`), therefore all properties from `GpsData` class will be serialized regardless of annotation.

If you want annotation to have effect you have to create `Gson` instance as `new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()` and to pass it to `GsonConverterFactory.create()`. Maybe it is affecting the server to not to serialize data properly, not sure though..

Second thing, it'd be useful to use `OkHttp` logging so that you can see HTTP request details in android studio console.

Here is the example of `OkHttpClient` which have `Content-Type` set for all endpoints, and you can remove `@Headers` from `GpsApiInterface`.

```
private OkHttpClient getClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE))
            .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                Request request = chain.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8")
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }).build();
}
```

and then modify Retrofit instantiation like this:

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://"+ DEBUG_API)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()))
            .client(getClient())
            .build();
```

When running in debug mode, you'll see HTTP request and responses in the console and it will be easier to debug. 
I am aware that this is not the complete answer, but it's one step to the solution. 
Waiting for the feedback.

**Update:**

Another thing to be aware of. If you're using `Retrofit2`, baseUrl (in your case `DEBUG_API` value) must end with `/` and in that case, starting `/` in `@POST("/api/v2/GPS")` is probably causing the problem since resulting endpoint url probably looks like this `http://DEBUG_API//api/v2/GPS`.
Try to modify method `POST` to `@POST("api/v2/GPS")`

Comment: I just updated my post with request logging and the differences between a working json and non working

Comment: Ah I see you've figured it out already. I didn't noticed `[]` on your server method. 
Glad that I could help. Cheers.